# Windows bat file remove all file and folder excluding some file and folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to delete files and folder in a directory excluding some file and folder in a bat file.

I need to keep these file, `update.bat FolderName.zip FolderName`  and all other should deleted from the directory,

I wrote the .bat file but seems `FolderName` also get deleted from directory, rest working fine.

Can anyone tell what wrong with below script?

```
attrib +r update.bat
attrib +r FolderName.zip
attrib +r FolderName
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
attrib -r update.bat
attrib -r FolderName.zip
attrib -r FolderName
```

Thanks 
Haris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how "Read Only" works for folders in Windows. It's not your fault. It's a misleading label. "Read Only" on a folder makes all files *within* the folder read only, [but not the folder itself](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/prevent-changes-to-a-file-or-folder-read-only).

> **Note**
>
> Setting a folder to read-only makes all the files in the folder read-only. It does not affect the folder itself.

My apologies for quoting the Vista documentation, I wasn't able to find a similar page for folders for Windows 7. It is mentioned in the UI though:

[image: Read only setting]

---

#### How do we work around this?

We are going to set the [`system`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute as well.

```
attrib +r update.bat
attrib +r FolderName.zip
attrib +r +s FolderName
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
attrib -r update.bat
attrib -r FolderName.zip
attrib -r -s FolderName
```

---

Example utilization:

Before running update, my directory contains the following:

```
<DIR>   FolderName
        FolderName.zip
        New Bitmap Image.bmp
<DIR>   New folder
        New Microsoft Word Document.docx
        New Text Document (2).txt
        New Text Document (3).txt
        New Text Document.txt
        update.bat
```

After executing the `update.bat`, the directory now looks like this:

```
<DIR>   FolderName
        FolderName.zip
        update.bat
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed answer, actually this is the first time I writing a script in windows. Now while running, the folder not getting deleted but I am getting the message like `E:\Qt_Project\Newfolder\a>update.bat
The directory name is invalid.
E:\Qt_Project\Newfolder\a\FolderName.zip
Access is denied.
The directory name is invalid.` does that expected?

Comment: The change I made to the script doesn't affect what you had for the `.zip` file. Is that created by a user other than the one running the batch file? It's possible permissions aren't set up allowing you to modify the attributes.

Comment: Yes the zip file are downloaded from a server. My ultimate purpose is update my application, for that I downloaded the zip file from server, now extract it to the folder where my current application located . Then delete all files and folder from the application directory(except the batch file(used to do all these operation), newly downloaded zip file,extracted folder) then copy back newly extracted application file to current directory, then launch the application.

Answer (score 2):

While it is usually used to copy files, with a proper setup `robocopy` can also handle file/folder removal. All that is needed is an empty folder as source, your folder to clear as target and the `/purge` switch will remove all files in target not present in source. File and folder retention is handled with `/xf` (exclude files) and `/xd` (exclude directories) switches

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "target=%~1"
    if not defined target set "target=%cd%"

    set "excludedFiles=update.cmd foldername.zip"
    set "excludedFolders=folderName"

    2>nul (
        for %%a in ("%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do (
            md "%%~fa" 
            robocopy "%%~fa" "%target%\." /l /s /e /nocopy /purge /xf %excludedFiles% /xd %excludedFolders%
            rmdir /s /q "%%~fa" 
        )
    )
```

The `robocopy` command includes a `/l` switch to only list the files/folders involved in the operation. If everything seems right, remove the `/l` to perform file/folder removal.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to using TotalCommander with Synchronize Dirs options, make one empty folder for Synchronize.

Comment: Try to provide more explanation to your answers. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.

Comment: The question you are answering requires a solution to work in a batch file and you are recommending the use of a GUI tool which could be harder to run automatically